# Creating tarball of files every week in bash script

Tags: bash, tar

I have directories in the form `/var/log/2015-03-01/192.168.56.101_SW1002`
The `2015-XX-XX` directories need to be put into a tarball every week.
The script logic I have so far is:

```
if (-mtime % 7 == 0) && (file extension != .tar)
{

tar -xvvcf /var/log/(most recent date).tar `grep -v *.tar`

}
```

How can I translate this logic into a bash script?

Thanks.

Comment: use [cron](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) to setup your job.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that by running a cron job every week, but if for some reason the folder 2014-03-01 is not created then it will create a .tar file excluding it.. as in I want the script to be based on the fact the files are 7 days old or less, not run a cron job every 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set up a counter and loop through a range of dates, archiving anything from the most recently completed week.  For instance:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGDIR='.'
DATECMD='gdate'
WEEKENDING='Sunday'

ENDDATE=`$DATECMD -d "last $WEEKENDING" +%Y-%m-%d`
STARTDATE=`$DATECMD -d "$ENDDATE -6 days" +%Y-%m-%d`
OFN="week_ending_$ENDDATE.tar"

if [ ! -f "$OFN" ]; then
    for i in `seq 0 6`; do
        LOOPDATE=`$DATECMD -d "$STARTDATE +$i days" +%Y-%m-%d`
        if [ -d $LOGDIR/$LOOPDATE ]; then
            if [ -f "$OFN" ]; then
                tar rvf "$OFN" "$LOGDIR/$LOOPDATE/"
            else
                tar cvf "$OFN" "$LOGDIR/$LOOPDATE/"
            fi
        fi
    done
fi
```

The above script could be run without trouble any time within the week following the preceding week close date.  On GNU systems, set DATECMD to 'date'.

Note, your tar command is screwy.  You cannot both create (-c) an extract (-x) and archive at the same time.